# Obtaining different variables from wavelet function outputs in R

Tags: r, for-loop, time-series, lapply, wavelet

I am pretty new to R and I am trying to obtain the outputs from a wavelet function on my data. My data is structured as [152, 90], 152 timepoints from 90 variables. I would like to transform each time series(columns) into wavelets. I was able to obtain wavelets for 1 timeseries and attempted to loop through the columns and get the 4 different outputs I want in different variables.

```
data <- read.table(data.txt,sep = "\t")
rois <- seq(1,90,by = 1)
for ( i in 1:length(rois) ) {
a <- data[,i]
b <- wavMODWT(a, wavelet = "s14", n.levels = 4)
data1.d1[i] <- b$data$d1
data1.d2[i] <- b$data$d2
data1.d3[i] <- b$data$d3
data1.d4[i] <- b$data$d4
}
```

I was hoping that this would give me a 152 x 90 matrix/dataframe for each "d" output from the wavMODT function. I get the "error in data1[i] <- b$data$d1 : object 'data1' not found. I tried to make data1 an empty list but got another error " number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length".

Also, would this be a good time to use the apply() functions since I am trying to apply a function over multiple columns?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

Edit: here is my sample data. The function takes column V1 as the input and outputs 4 column vectors of the same length (b$data$1 to b$data$4). The wavMODWT function is in the package: wmtsa

```
  V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6
1   1321.837 1353.712 1250.450 1183.120 1263.095 1298.410
2   1327.204 1360.711 1249.475 1181.297 1266.686 1294.568
3   1328.402 1362.084 1249.310 1177.071 1271.967 1295.823
4   1327.890 1366.335 1248.203 1173.392 1273.039 1295.118
5   1327.157 1370.059 1252.110 1177.771 1274.428 1300.177
6   1329.278 1370.950 1250.477 1177.238 1277.021 1294.408
7   1330.106 1363.459 1247.602 1176.267 1272.182 1296.256
8   1327.378 1364.607 1248.047 1178.523 1271.818 1293.098
9   1327.867 1363.442 1245.530 1175.825 1268.713 1295.788
```

Comment: additionally, I have 211 subjects each with 152 time points from 90 variables. Is there a shortcut I can take to obtain the wavelet outputs from every subject without a for loop?

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example of your data? It would make answering your question much easier.

Comment: Thank you for replying @BLT . I edited the main question to include a sample of my data.

Comment: Your example data will not work with your code, as there are not 90 columns.  That means that you do not have a reproducible example.  Please re-write your example so that it might have a chance of being run by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Since [wavMODWT](https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/wmtsa/html/wavMODWT.html) returns a *wavTransform* class object, I played around with this object in the embedded R console on the [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/wmtsa/versions/2.0-2/topics/wavTransform) page.

Consider, using `lapply` to retrieve a list of data frames each with 4 columns for coefficient vectors. The number of data frames would equal the number of columns you pass into `lapply`, specifically your time series inputs, so N=90:

```
data <- read.table(data.txt, sep = "\t")

# CREATING LIST OF DATA FRAMES
dfList <- lapply(seq(ncol(data)), function(s) { 
    W <- wavMODWT(s,  wavelet = "s14", n.levels = 4)  

    data.frame(list(d1=as.vector(W$data$d1)), 
               list(d2=as.vector(W$data$d4)), 
               list(d3=as.vector(W$data$d3)), 
               list(d4=as.vector(W$data$d4))) 
})

# NAMING EACH ELEMENT IN DF LIST TO CORRESPONDING COLUMN NAME
dfList <- setNames(dfList, colnames(data))
```

To iterate across the subjects wrap above assignments in another `lapply` that receives the 211 distinct subject datasets as input to ultimately output a list of 211 *dfLists* each of which has 90 data frames! Below example assumes data is retrieved from text files.

```
datatxts <- list.files(path="/path/to/folder", pattern=".txt")

subjectsList <- lapply(datatxts, function(d) {

    dfList <- lapply(seq(ncol(d)), function(s) { ... })
    setNames(dfList, colnames(d))
})

subjectsList <- setNames(subjectsLists, gsub(".txt", "", datatxts))
```

Comment: Don't quite know if that's a thank you for effort, or thank you it worked. If this answer helped, please accept it (tick mark to side) to confirm resolution.